# Programmatically change button image source WPSL 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-silverlight

This is my xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="FlashButton"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Click="FlashButton_Click">
<Button.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="70"
              Height="70">
            <Ellipse Stroke="White" 
                     StrokeThickness="3"/>
            <Image x:Name="FlashButtonImage" 
                   Source="/Assets/Images/flashOn.png" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Button.ContentTemplate>
```

It creates a circle button with a flash image in it. When I press the button I want to change FlashButtonImage source to `"/Assets/Images/flashOn.png"` but I can't access the image inside it. Is it a simple way to design this type of button or you can help me with some code for accessing image source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this code instead:

```
<Button x:Name="FlashButton"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Click="FlashButton_Click">
    <Grid Width="70"
          Height="70">
        <Ellipse Stroke="White" 
                 StrokeThickness="3"/>
        <Image x:Name="FlashButtonImage" 
               Source="/Assets/Images/flashOn.png" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```